# AJAX code attached to submit event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't get a form to submit inside an ajax success function:

```
$('#formId').on('submit', function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault(); 
});

$('#submit').on('click', this.doStuff);

doStuff: function () {
    $.get('url').done(function (data) {
        if (data.IsSuccessful) {
            $('#formId').off('submit');
            $('#formId').submit();
        }
        else {
        }
    });
}
```

Weirdly it will do the submit the second time this event is triggered, but not the first, and it will submit independently with those 2 lines of code, but not inside the get (the debugger does hit it). How can I submit a form based on an ajax call being successful?

Comment: I think it should be `$('#submit').on('click', this.doStuff);` <= Notice `()` removed after `doStuff`

Comment: @Satpal yeah sorry my typo - edited!

Answer (score 4):

`e.preventDefault();` method prevent form past and redirects to ajax call. Try this:

```
 $('#submit').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.get('url').done(function (data) {
                if (data.IsSuccessful) {
                    $('#formId').submit();
                }
                else {

                }
        });
     });
```

Comment: Please, add some explanation to your answer.

Comment: e.preventDefault(); method prevent form past and redirects to ajax call.

Comment: You should better edit your answer in order to add the explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

Tweaking your code a bit:

The `submit` event will handle all the logic. Therefore, no matter how your form gets submitted, the event will trigger.

```
var check = false;
$('#formId').on('submit', function (e) { 
    return check;
});

$('#submit').on('click', function(){
   $.get('url').done(function (data) {
       if (data.IsSuccessful) {
          check = true;
          $('#formId').submit();
       }
       else
       {
         check = false;
       }
    });
    return false;        
});
```

Comment: This seems to be always triggering the submit, when I only want to do it when the ajax is successful

Comment: Modified the code a bit, to fix the `return` code not working properly.

Comment: Remodifed again, and remove the logic from the `submit` event. This is due to the fact that, Ajax is ASYNC and checks won't be performed in time.

Comment: It still doesn't do the submit at all, hits the breakpoint though

Comment: Make sure, your ajax is being called properly and the `data` variable returned is parsed as a JSON object.